# How to fix UART communication between a Particle and ATMEGA8535

Tags: avr, uart, atmega, particles

So the setup is the following: I have RX and TX pins of a ATMEGA8535 connected to the corresponding pins on a Particle (a bidirectional logic level converter is in between to not fry the Particle). When sending data from the ATMEGA the Particle is receiving data, but what is received is different from what is sent in a interesting way. When sending the series of integers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... at first the Particle interprets the sent bytes correctly, but when it reaches 31 the next number is 0 again. After this second received 0 it will start 'counting' again till it reaches 63, where it will jump to 32. Similar behavior happens at 95 (jumps to 64) and 127 (jumps to 96).

The code on the particle is:

```
void setup() {
  // Start the serial connection
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    // Reading the received byte and publishing it to the particle cloud
    int in = Serial1.read();
    Particle.publish("test", String(in));
  }
}
```

The code on the ATMEGA is:

```
#define F_CPU 1000720UL //CPU frequency

#include <xc.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUD 9600 // baud
#define BRC ((F_CPU/16/BAUD) - 1)

int main(void) {
    
    /* Set baud rate */
    //UBRRH = (unsigned char)(baud>>8);
    //UBRRL = (unsigned char)baud;
    UBRRH = (BRC >> 8);
    UBRRL =  BRC;
    
    /* Enable receiver and transmitter and Set frame format: 9data, 2stop bit */
    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)|(1<<UCSZ2);
    UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<URSEL)|(1<<USBS);
    
    // The counter variable
    int i = 0;
    
    while(1){
        // Setting the UART data register to send the counter and incrementing the counter
        UDR = i;
        i++; 
        
        _delay_ms(400);
    }
}
```

Thing I've tried/checked:

- Using a oscilloscope I've check that the send signal continues in a regular fashion when the jumps appear.
- I've altered the frame format, but anything less than 9 bits results in even weirder behaviour (with 8 data bits it starts counting at 128) and the number of stop bits does not seem to influence much.
- The ATMEGA is not hooked up to crystal to keep the clock freq consistent, so I used the `_delay_ms()` function to 'tune' the clock frequency of the ATMEGA.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some bits from the frame are missed. This may happen when UART speed of the transmitter and the receiver is different.

For your speed calculation you're using plain USART mode, and calculate UBRR like this:

```
#define F_CPU 1000720UL //CPU frequency
...
#define BAUD 9600 // baud
#define BRC ((F_CPU/16/BAUD) - 1)
```

in this formula BRC is 1000720/16/9600 - 1 and rounded downward equals to 5
therefore actual USART speed is

*1000720 (assuming this is the real CPU frequency) / 16 / (UBRR + 1) = **10424***, which is 8.5% higher than required 9600, which makes communication over UART impossible.

To avoid this problem you can use 2X mode of the USART. For that set the `U2X` bit in the `UCSRA` register, and use 8 (insted of 16) divisor for UBRR calculation

```
#define BRC ((F_CPU/8/BAUD) - 1)

...

    UCSRA = (1<<U2X);
    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)|(1<<UCSZ2);
    UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<URSEL)|(1<<USBS);
```

Now BRC value is 1000720/8/9600 - 1 and rounded downward equals to 12

and actual USART baudrate will be:

*1000720/8/(12 + 1) = **9622***, which is only 0.2% higher than required